# Returning a Unix Timestamp when querying a DateTimeField

Tags: python, django

In Django, I have the following query

```
dates = (
  Event.objects.filter(cancelled=False)
  .exclude(id=event.id)
  .aggregate(
    first_date=Min('start'),
    last_date=Max('start'),
    next_date=Min('start', filter=Q(date__gt=timezone.now().date())),
    recent_date=Max('start', filter=Q(end__lt=timezone.now()))
  )
)
```

and I would like to annotate the query so that my lesson dates are returned as unix timestamps rather than datetime objects. I recognize I can simply do something like `dates.next_date.timestamp()`, but this causes an error when `dates.next_date` is `None`, and I'd rather not have to repeatedly check that my object is not None before getting its timestamp. How could I go about this?

I have searched through many other answers and the Django docs but haven't been able to find anything I could specifically apply here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What would you prefer to happen when `dates.next_date` is `None`?

Comment: @ChrisSears I don't want to have to timestamp it in the first place. If my query returns timestamps I don't have to process the data to turn all my datetimes into timestamps while avoiding Nones

Comment: Have you considered storing using something like this: https://pypi.org/project/django-unixtimestampfield/

Comment: @ChrisSears Appreciate the idea, but it's a small enough problem I don't think it's worth changing the schema over. Thought there might be some way I could run the data through a function before I return it but haven't been able to find a way.